# How can I call all entries in an arraylist to be displayed on a graph in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mpandroidchart

I apologize if I worded this poorly but for the sake of clarity I will explain as best I can. I'm using MPAndroidChart to draw a line graph and I followed this tutorial to get it up and running https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-line-chart-using-mpandroidchart-tutorial/#Defining_X-axis_labels. I've made some adjustments to suit my needs and so on.

On button click, I call a method that adds another entry using the value of the edit text field, at the position that i increment each button press so the code is something like `entries.add(new Entry(editTextValue, numEntries));`This does what I want it to do while I'm looking at the current activity screen, with the previous value remaining, and the next value being added. However, once i leave that activity and return to it, only the last value remains. My understanding is that I need to have a for loop that will iterate over each element in arraylist when I call the drawGraph method that I'm using, but I haven't had any luck with this. I've tried to use `for(Entry e: entries)` and use e in place of numEntries, but the data type is not compatible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: `public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int counter = 0;
    public ArrayList entries = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int lifetimeNums;
    public static int nums = 0;
    public static int numEntries;

```
public static String entryLabel = Integer.toString(numEntries);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    reDrawGraph();
}



// Graphing method
public void reDrawGraph(){

    LineChart chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(100);
    chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaxValue(100);


    //Creating list of entries


    LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    // creating labels
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 + numEntries; i++) {
        labels.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }


    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);

    entries.add(new Entry(testActivity.nums, numEntries));

    chart.animateXY(1000,1000);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.invalidate();
    chart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart

}

public void counterClicked(View view){

    try {

        EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_val);
        int localNums = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText().toString());

        if (counter < 3) {
            nums += localNums;
            counter++;
            numEntries++;

            Toast.makeText(this, "Total Entries" + entries.get(0),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            reDrawGraph();
            inputText.getText().clear();
        }

        if (counter == 3){
            lifetimeNums++;
            numEntries++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectionActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {


        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a value",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`
```

Comment: We can't troubleshoot isolated lines of code. Include a more complete snippet.

Comment: @PoringSlayer  You really need to provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's really difficult to see what the issue is without being able to see your code

Comment: Here's the entire activity that is updating the graph.